# Error in android studio while downloading sdk

Tags: android-studio

[java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK
package Android Emulator: Read timed out.]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2q0c.png)

This error is not resolving I tried everything reinstall,checking connection,running as administrator etc but nothings working this is the latest 2024 version of android studi